# Visibility converter in MVVM not updating

Tags: c#, mvvm, visibility, converters

I want to change the visibility of a `Grid` depending on whether the value of some `TextBoxes` is larger than other `TextBoxes`. I'm using MVVM and have the following code:

XAML

```xml
<UserControl.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="TimeError" Visibility="{Binding Path=IsTimeValid, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    <TextBlock Text="Incorrect value"/>
</Grid>

<TextBox x:Name="TotalStarthh" MaxLength="2" FontSize="16" Width="28" Text="{Binding TotalStarthh}"/>
<more TextBoxes/>
```

In the ViewModel I parse the `textBoxes` to an integer value and calculate the total time.

```cs
private string _TotalStarthh;
public string TotalStarthh
{
    get { return _TotalStarthh; }
    set { _TotalStarthh = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
//The same for the other TextBoxes.

public int Totalstart()
{
    int.TryParse(TotalStarthh, out int TShh);
    int.TryParse(TotalStartmm, out int TSmm);
    int.TryParse(TotalStartss, out int TSss);
    //calculating hours:mins:sec to total seconds
    //This can be over 24 hours so datetime is not used
    int Totalstart = TShh * 3600 + TSmm * 60 + TSss;
    return Totalstart;
}

public int Totalend()
{
    int.TryParse(TotalEndhh, out int TEhh);
    int.TryParse(TotalEndmm, out int TEmm);
    int.TryParse(TotalEndss, out int TEss);
    //calculating hours:mins:sec to total seconds
    //This can be over 24 hours so datetime is not used
    int Totalend = TEhh * 3600 + TEmm * 60 + TEss;
    return Totalend;
}

// validate that start time is lower than end time.
public bool IsTimeValid
{
    get { return (Totalstart > Totalend); }
    set { NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

But this doesn't update the Visibility of the `Grid`. Am I doing the `NotifyPropertyChanged` incorrectly? I'm fairly new to mvvm and am still trying to grasp it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you IsTimeValid property setter is never called. at least not in this code snippet. and there's the important NotifiyPropertyChanged that should happen..

Comment: To trigger the Converter you have to raise the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` of your `IsTimeValid`. So you could add `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsTimeValid));` to the setter of your `TotalStarthh`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `TotalStarthh`property changes. And your UI is notified about that. But you never notified the UI that `IsTimeValid` might have changed, too.

You can either make `IsTimeValid` a normal property and set it to the boolean value you want every time a dependent property changes.

Or you can notify the UI that `IsTimeValid` has changed every time you change the two properties used. To explain how, we'd need to know what your `NotifyPropertyChanged` actually looks like.

If I'd have to take a guess, I'd say this might do the trick:

```
public string TotalStarthh
{
    get { return _TotalStarthh; }
    set 
    {
         _TotalStarthh = value;
         NotifyPropertyChanged(); // notifies the UI this property has changed
         NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTimeValid"); // notifies the UI IsTimeValid has changed 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sometimes the solution is so simple haha.

Comment: I would suggest you use `nameof(IsTimeValid)`. This ensures that if you rename your property, the `NotifyPropertyChanged` is still working.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually set the property to the new value before notifying.
To achieve this, use a property with backing field.

```
private bool isTimeValid;
public bool IsTimeValid
{ 
  get { return (Totalstart > Totalend); }
  set
  {
    if(value != isTimeValid)
      {
        isTimeValid = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(IsTimeValid));
      }
   }
 }
```

Is strongly recommend to use Prism MVVM Framework though. It has a SetProperty function, which does all this work for you in a single line.